# Mongoose add same Schema more than one time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying through node js, express and mongoose to create a way to add the same mongoose Schema more than one time I want to use a trigger button. I have to restart the server to add more to the DB.

Later on I want to change it through a counter but first I need to get this working.

I am trying to solve it on my own but I got stuck, thank you for your help !

the app.js I use as server.

/app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const db = require("./database");
const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


app.use(express.static('DB'));
app.use('/Dev', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Dev', 'public')));

//Export function to new a .js file
var ClickyClicky = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    }},
    {
      timestamps: true, //time
    }
);
  
  var Clicky = mongoose.model('Click', ClickyClicky, 'clickystore');
  
  var Clicks = new Clicky({ name: 'Test' });
  //Export function to new a .js file
  
  
  //Save button trigger.
  app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  
    Clicks.save(function (err, book) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(book.name + " saved to bookstore collection.");
    });
  
  });


    //Save button trigger.
    app.post('/alfa', (req, res) => {
  
        Clicks.save(function (err, name) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          console.log(name.name + " saved to name  collection.");
        });
      
    });



// // 404 page
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('<h1>404, Page not found !</h1>');
});
  
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server started at http://localhost:5000');
});
```

/client.js

```
console.log('Client code running');

const testButton = document.getElementById('Button');

testButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('Butten was clicked');

    fetch('/test', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        console.log('Click was recorded');
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});

const testButton2 = document.getElementById('Button2');

testButton2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('Butten was clicked');

    fetch('/alfa', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        console.log('Click was recorded');
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="Button">Click me for a test!</button>
    <button id="Button2">Click me for a test1!</button>
</body>
<script src="./Dev/Client.js"></script>
</html>
```

\database.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOB_URI, () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});
```

Comment: Where do you get stuck? what is the current and expected result ? What errors are you getting Please update the question as well

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with adding, `unique: false` to my mongoose schema and deleted the old input from the BD